# Celery daemon - how to configure it to run multiple tasks from multiple Flask applications?

Tags: flask, rabbitmq, celery, daemon

I have a flask app `myapp_A` that uses celery to run some asynchronous tasks. And I have configured celery to run as a daemon process. Here is the service script.

**/etc/default/celery:**

```
# Name of nodes to start
CELERYD_NODES="w1"

# Absolute or relative path to the 'celery' command:
CELERY_BIN="/var/www/myapp_A.com/public_html/venv/bin/celery"

# App instance to use
CELERY_APP="myapp_A.celery"

# Where to chdir at start.
CELERYD_CHDIR="/var/www/myapp_A.com/public_html/"

# Extra command-line arguments to the worker
CELERYD_OPTS="--time-limit=300 --concurrency=8"

# %n will be replaced with the first part of the nodename.
CELERYD_LOG_FILE="/var/log/celery/%n%I.log"
CELERYD_PID_FILE="/var/run/celery/%n.pid"
CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL="INFO"

# Workers should run as an unprivileged user.
CELERYD_USER="myuser"
CELERYD_GROUP="www-data"

# If enabled pid and log directories will be created if missing,
# and owned by the userid/group configured.
CELERY_CREATE_DIRS=1
```

**/etc/init.d/celeryd:**

Celery's generic one from [here](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/master/extra/generic-init.d/celeryd).

---

Now I have another Flask app `myapp_B` that requires celery to run tasks as well.

- How should I configure for this?
- Should I create another daemon process under a different name?
- How should I configure my message broker (RabbitMQ) for multiple celery process?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a single daemon process to work with both applications.
one way is to to use different queue names for different applications
Here is the config I'm using

```
celery worker -A init_celery --quiet --loglevel=$WORKER_LOG_LEVEL --concurrency=4 --queues=que1,que2
```

Then specify the queue name in each application. using

```
CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE = 'que1'
```

Comment: Thanks. So what should I configure for `CELERY_BIN`, `CELERY_APP`, `CELERYD_CHDIR`. Should I move these configs into respective apps? If yes, how should I pass these variables to the daemon script?

Comment: There is a good example in the following official doc.
https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/daemonizing.html.
Post here if you face trouble.

Comment: Hi, I did read the documentation. What I don't get is how do you define `CELERY_BIN` when you have celery installed inside two `venv`s? And where should I configure `CELERY_APP` when I have two apps and what directory should celery start in `CELERYD_CHDIR` when it's being used by two applications?

Comment: One specificaion would be to start multiple nodes using
`CELERYD_NODES="worker1 worker2 worker3"`
then specify options for these workers using
`CELERYD_OPTS="--time-limit=300 -c 8 -c:worker2 4 -c:worker3 2 -Ofair:worker1"`
You can Configure node-specific settings by appending node name to arguments:

You can find all the options using
`celery worker --help`

Comment: If I'm thinking clearly `CELERY_BIN` path can be specified using  `--executable` option for worker
-A to specify CELERY_APP
--workdir to specify CELERYD_CHDIR

Comment: So should I be creating two `ExecStart` in `celery.service` for two apps?

Comment: No. These can be specified in one

Comment: I tried specifying it in one line (configs has been posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59531542/celery-systemd-proper-configuration-for-two-applications-to-use-the-same-daemon)), but now it won't start and always end in an out of memory error. I'd be grateful if you could help me identify the mistake in my config. An example gist of the config file could help if it's not too much to ask. Or maybe a link to a resource that deals with this scenario.