# Celery systemd proper configuration for two applications to use the same daemon service

Tags: linux, bash, flask, celery, systemd

With some insights from my prev [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59466401/celery-daemon-how-to-configure-it-to-run-multiple-tasks-from-multiple-flask-ap), I reconfigured my celery to run as a daemon with systemd, but I am still facing issues configuring it for multiple apps. Celery [documentation](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/daemonizing.html#usage-systemd) (which shows how to daemonize for a single app) is insufficient for me to understand about multiple apps. And I am less experienced with daemonizing anything.

So far, this is my configuration for the service to enable both the applications to use it.

**/etc/conf.d/celery**

```
CELERYD_NODES="w1 w2 w3"

# Absolute or relative path to the 'celery' command:
CELERY_BIN_appA="/var/www/appA/public_html/venv/bin/celery"
CELERY_BIN_appB="/var/www/appB/public_html/venv/bin/celery"

# App instances
CELERY_APP_appA="appA.celery"
CELERY_APP_appB="appB.celery"

# How to call manage.py
CELERYD_MULTI="multi"

# Extra command-line arguments to the worker
CELERYD_OPTS="--time-limit=300 --concurrency=8"

# - %n will be replaced with the first part of the nodename.
# - %I will be replaced with the current child process index
#   and is important when using the prefork pool to avoid race conditions.
CELERYD_PID_FILE="/var/run/celery/%n.pid"
CELERYD_LOG_FILE="/var/log/celery/%n%I.log"
CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL="INFO"

# Celery Beat
CELERYBEAT_PID_FILE="/var/run/celery/beat.pid"
CELERYBEAT_LOG_FILE="/var/log/celery/beat.log"
```

**/etc/systemd/system/celery.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=Celery Service
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=myuser
Group=www-data
EnvironmentFile=/etc/conf.d/celery
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c '${CELERY_BIN_appA} multi start ${CELERYD_NODES} \
  -A ${CELERY_APP_appA} --pidfile=${CELERYD_PID_FILE} \
  --logfile=${CELERYD_LOG_FILE} --loglevel=${CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL} --workdir=/var/www/appA/public_html/ ${CELERYD_OPTS} && ${CELERY_BIN_appB} multi start ${CELERYD_NODES} \
  -A ${CELERY_APP_appB} --pidfile=${CELERYD_PID_FILE} \
  --logfile=${CELERYD_LOG_FILE} --loglevel=${CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL} --workdir=/var/www/appB/public_html/ ${CELERYD_OPTS}'
ExecStop=/bin/bash -c '${CELERY_BIN_appA} multi stopwait ${CELERYD_NODES} \
  --pidfile=${CELERYD_PID_FILE} && ${CELERY_BIN_appB} multi stopwait ${CELERYD_NODES} \
  --pidfile=${CELERYD_PID_FILE}'
ExecReload=/bin/bash -c '${CELERY_BIN_appA} multi restart ${CELERYD_NODES} \
  -A ${CELERY_APP_appA} --pidfile=${CELERYD_PID_FILE} \
  --logfile=${CELERYD_LOG_FILE} --loglevel=${CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL} ${CELERYD_OPTS} && ${CELERY_BIN_appB} multi restart ${CELERYD_NODES} \
  -A ${CELERY_APP_appB} --pidfile=${CELERYD_PID_FILE} \
  --logfile=${CELERYD_LOG_FILE} --loglevel=${CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL} ${CELERYD_OPTS}'

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When I try to start the service, I get an OOM.

**Traceback:**

```
● celery.service - Celery Service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/celery.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2019-12-30 18:31:02 IST; 16s ago
  Process: 28806 ExecStart=/bin/bash -c ${CELERY_BIN_appA} multi start ${CELERYD_NODES}    -A ${CELERY_APP_appA} --pidfile=${CELERYD_PID_FILE}    --logfile=${CELERYD_LOG_FILE} --log

Dec 30 18:31:00 claudia bash[28806]:   File "/var/www/appB/public_html/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/apps/multi.py", line 196, in _waitexec
Dec 30 18:31:00 claudia bash[28806]:     pipe = Popen(argstr, env=env)
Dec 30 18:31:00 claudia bash[28806]:   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 729, in __init__
Dec 30 18:31:00 claudia bash[28806]:     restore_signals, start_new_session)
Dec 30 18:31:00 claudia bash[28806]:   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1295, in _execute_child
Dec 30 18:31:00 claudia bash[28806]:     restore_signals, start_new_session, preexec_fn)
Dec 30 18:31:00 claudia bash[28806]: OSError: [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory
Dec 30 18:31:00 claudia systemd[1]: celery.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Dec 30 18:31:02 claudia systemd[1]: celery.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Dec 30 18:31:02 claudia systemd[1]: Failed to start Celery Service.
```

Please break down the process for me and help me understand what is wrong here and how to configure this properly.

Comment: please post code of your celery task.

Comment: @TalhaJunaid, for both of my apps I have tasks similar to [this](https://gist.github.com/claudiamaximus/e729a6318210084cfcd6e97852d66103) in my views. Some of the tasks need to be run in app context too to do some database operations. So the celery object itself is instantiated with [this](https://gist.github.com/claudiamaximus/bc617fe72e6b64912b5f6dbc989ce236) code.

Comment: Hello @Claudia, I have the same problem. Did you ever manage to make it work? What was your final config? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You should have **two separate** systemd scripts for different Celery workers, something like `celery-appA.service` and `celery-appB.service`. Also, you do not need `/bin/bash -c` to run the worker. Instead create a virtual environment and use the full path to the Celery script in the environment. Let's assume you have created a virtual environment in `/opt/celery/venv` and installed Celery there (with something like `/opt/celery/venv/bin/pip3 install celery[redis,msgpack]`). Then instead of `/bin/bash -c ...` you can simply do `/opt/celery/venv/bin/celery worker -A ...`.

Before you run Celery worker check what is using the memory. It could be that some old Celery workers are still running, and consume your system resources.

Comment: Thanks. I will try this solution. But before I do this, is there any way to configure a single Celery service to use two queues, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59467062/12164092)? I am more interested in this approach, and would like to know if anything is wrong in my above configurations.

Comment: The only way I know is to use `celery multi` and I see you already use it in your configuration. Keep in mind that celery multi actually starts one or more separate, independent Celery workers. It is (almost) the same as having them separately.

Comment: @claudia:  two queues or two brokers?

Comment: @2ps, two queues handled by one broker interfacing one celery service that's running as a daemon.

Comment: @DejanLekic, thanks. As I am using `celery multi`, is my config the right way to use in my case? It could help if there's an example config file or a resource that deals with two apps configured to run with two independent queues spawned by a single celery service.